# How to extrapolate data using the second order rate equation?

Tags: calculus, extrapolation

I would like to model the second order rate equation using the following criteria:
\begin{align}
A_\text{initial}&=8\,500\,000,\\
A_\text{final}  &=1\,200\,000,\\
t               &=38. 
\end{align}

I'd like to create a plot that looks like the 2nd order chart shown in the following image:
[image: interpolation chart]

How can I use my criteria to extrapolate the data in between $A_\text{initial}$ and $A_\text{final}$?

Comment: Extrapolating data between two points is usually known as interpolation. Also, the notation in the chart is very, very odd IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The second order differential rate law is $-\frac{d[A]}{dt} = k[A]^2$

First separate the two varaibles: $[A]$ and $t$ by putting them on different sides of the equation

$-\frac{d[A]}{[A]^2} = k\ dt$

Now integrate both sides

$\int -\frac{d[A]}{[A]^2} = \int k\ dt$

Doing the integration gives the formula describing the concentration as a function of time:

$\frac{1}{[A]} = kt+c$

The value $c$ is an unknown constant from the integration. There is also the unknown constant $k$, we will have to use your data to find these two constants.

First, at the starting time ($t=0$) you know that $[A]=8.5 \times 10^6$. Putting this into the formula we got from integrating gives:

$\frac{1}{8.5 \times 10^6} = k(0)+c$

So clearly $c=\frac{1}{8.5 \times 10^6}$. Now put that information into the formula that relates concentration and time

$\frac{1}{[A]} = kt+\frac{1}{8.5 \times 10^6}$

Now use your data for the final time. When $t=38$ then $[A] = 1.2 \times 10^6$

$\frac{1}{1.2 \times 10^6} = k(38)+\frac{1}{8.5 \times 10^6}$

This gives us the value of $k$:

$k = \frac{1}{38}(\frac{1}{1.2 \times 10^6} - \frac{1}{8.5 \times 10^6}) \approx 1.88 \times 10^{-8}$

Finally, putting this value of $k$ into the formula for concentration gives:

$\frac{1}{[A]} = (1.88 \times 10^{-8})t+\frac{1}{8.5 \times 10^6}$

You can use this formula to predict the concentration for any time $t$

Comment: thank you! this was perfect. my next question is how to compare the First Order and Second Order models. with the First Order model, I can use `k` as an annual percent reduction. is there a way to figure out what the annual percent reduction would be for the Second Order equation?

Comment: also, would you be able to derive what the third order rate equation, and how I could use it to interpolate the data between the same points?

Comment: I could have just told you the final answer but instead I showed you how to get there. Now you can repeat that method for the third order equation. Stack exchange is for learning, not for getting answers.

Comment: Thanks Hugh! I'm happy to take it from here...To get started, do I derive    -(d[A]/dt) = k[A]^3 ?

Comment: You can start with the rate equation -(d[A]/dt) = k[A]^3 and then prepare it for integration by separating the variables so that it becomes -d[A]/[A]^3 = k dt

Comment: Solved it, thanks Hugh! Just out of curiosity, why is the rate equation defined as -d[A]/dt = k[A]^power. Why did it get derived this way?

Comment: I assume you're using this for chemistry. If the concentration is [A] then the rate at which [A] changes (d[A]/dt) is the rate of the reaction. You know from chemistry theory that when the reactants have a higher concentration that makes the reaction quicker so d[A]/dt is larger when [A] is larger. We don't have an exact way to predict how [A] affects the rate of reaction but we just assume that when [A] doubles then d[A]/dt doubles, the equations that fits this behavior is d[A]/dt  = k[A]

Comment: When you test some reactions to check if d[A]/dt = k[A] is an accurate way to describe the chemical reaction you might find that it is inaccurate. The initial assumption "when [A] doubles then d[A]/dt doubles" was not accurate. To try to get a better model for the chemical reaction we can use a slightly .ore complicated equation like d[A]/dt = k[A]^power. That's where the power comes from. These are all just guesses for what model might work well, they don't come from fundamental laws of chemistry.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Hugh. I'm curious how the First Order (FO) Rate Equation compares to the Compounded Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) equation `(Final/Initial)^(1/t)-1.` Using the same numbers as above the CAGR is -5.02% while the FO rate is -5.15%. Can you explain the difference between these equations?

Comment: Also, when I interpolate out to t=38, the final values are 355,730 for FO and 386,312 for the CAGR. It makes sense that they slightly differ, but shouldn't the interpolated value be 1,200,000?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A:\,\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ sends time to some value and you have two values: $$A(t_0)=A_\text{initial}\tag1\label{eq1}$$ and $$A(t_1)=A_\text{final},\tag2\label{eq2}$$
where $t_0=0$ is the time at which you have $A_\text{initial}=8\,500\,000$ and $t_1=38$ is the time at which you have $A_\text{final}=1\,200\,000$,

and you want $A$ to satisfy the following differential equation:
$$-\frac{\mathrm dA(t)}{\mathrm dt}=kA(t)^2$$
(which I'm not sure is exactly what the notation in the picture means),

divide it by $-A(t)^2$ to have
$$\frac{\mathrm dA(t)}{A(t)^2\mathrm dt}=-k$$
and integrate with respect to $t$:
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{\mathrm dA(t)}{A(t)^2\mathrm dt}\,\mathrm dt=-\int k\,\mathrm dt\\
\iff&\int\frac{\mathrm dA(t)}{A(t)^2}=-kt+c_1\\
\iff&-\frac1{A(t)}+c_2=-kt+c_1;
\end{align}
of course, the use of two integration constants in this case is superfluous, so define $c_3=c_2-c_1$ and subtract $c_2$ from both sides:
$$-\frac1{A(t)}=-kt+c_1-c_2=-kt-(c_2-c_1)=-kt-c_3;$$
now just invert and multiply both sides by $-1$:
$$A(t)=\frac1{kt+c_3};\tag3\label{eq3}$$
now recall you have the first two equations $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$ and observe the form $\eqref{eq3}$ has two free variables $k$ and $c_3$, in which we can write the system
\begin{cases}
A_\text{initial}=A(t_0)=\dfrac1{kt_0+c_3},\\
A_\text{final}=A(t_1)=\dfrac1{kt_1+c_3};
\end{cases}
now recall $t_0=0$, so we trivially have $c_3=1/A(0)$, which leaves us with one equation:
$$A_\text{final}=A(t_1)=\dfrac1{kt_1+1/A_\text{initial}};$$
invert it:
$$\frac1{A_\text{final}}=kt_1+\frac1{A_\text{initial}};$$
subtract $1/A_\text{initial}$ from both sides:
$$kt_1=\frac1{A_\text{final}}-\frac1{A_\text{initial}};$$
divide both sides by $t_1$:
$$k=\frac1{t_1A_\text{final}}-\frac1{t_1A_\text{initial}};$$
now substitute it all back into $\eqref{eq3}$:
$$A(t)=\frac1{kt+c_3}=1\Big/\left(\left(\frac1{t_1A_\text{final}}-\frac1{t_1A_\text{initial}}\right)t+\frac1{A_\text{initial}}\right);$$
now just substitute your original numerical values into the last expression and evaluate it at whatever point $t$ you want.